# PrimeFaces Scrollable DataTable

Tags: primefaces, datatable, scrollable

I am facing this problem with PrimeFaces DataTable with `scrollable="true"`, the columns get shrink and the column header  doesn't align with the columns. I have seen a lot of posts on StackOverflow about the same problem, but couldn't get the solution, does any one have the solution now???

```
<p:dataTable id="idDataTbl" 
styleClass="lineItemDataTableQS hightLines" draggableColumns="false"
binding="#{<someBean>.<dataTable>}"
scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150" 
rows="25" value="#{<someBean>.<dataModel>}" 
rowSelectListener="#{<someBean>.<methodCall>}" 
selectionMode="single" 
var="lineItemData" 
rowsPerPageTemplate="5,25" 
rowIndexVar="lineRowIndex" 
selection="#{quoteSummaryBackingBean.selectedlineItemRowsList}"> 
. 
. 
. 
. <lot of columns.. about 31> 
. 
. 
. 
</p:dataTable>
```

I cant post the code :( its in production i could be in trouble, here is code for datatable tag, and there are columns.

Comment: Please show us your code. It will help us, help you.

Comment: <p:dataTable id="idDataTbl" styleClass="lineItemDataTableQS hightLines"
draggableColumns="false" binding="#{<someBean>.<dataTable>}"
scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"
rows="25" value="#{<someBean>.<dataModel>}"
rowSelectListener="#{<someBean>.<methodCall>}"
selectionMode="single" var="lineItemData"
rowsPerPageTemplate="5,25" rowIndexVar="lineRowIndex"
selection="#{quoteSummaryBackingBean.selectedlineItemRowsList}">
.
.
.
.
<lot of columns.. about 31>
.
.
.
</p:dataTable>

I cant post the code :( its in production i could be in trouble,
here is code for datatable tag, and there are columns.

Comment: Add the code to your question, not in the comments!